# Find a (substring) inside a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a search function that can show partial result according to your search variable.

For example we are looking for a word "**abcde**".

We have records of strings like

"ioqwepasaea"
 "uhabcsdwe" 
 "ewqabcde" 
 "abcfeqs" 
"cdeeqwee"

So the results should show "uh**abc**sdwe" - "ewq**abcde**"- "**abc**feqs" - "**cde**eqwee"

Is this possible using Jquery? Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Yes. It's possible. Have you tried anything? What format are the results in? Can you please share some code.

Comment: Yes - it is possible to use regular expressions in JavaScript. What exactly is your question?

Comment: You want it to search for any of the chars you've typed?  That would return everything in your list above :s

Comment: This is a very broad question, not to mention you don't need jQuery to manipulate strings.

Comment: BenM I don't have a code yet. I'm still doing research about it.

Comment: RUJordan I'm just starting to understand jQuery and I'm not really sure why what I'm talking about can you please guide me?

Comment: Are you implementing the search, the output, or both? In all cases, a quick google will give you tons of information to work with. Even on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching for substrings inside strings is done by using regular expressions.

Regular expressions (RegEx) can be used in javascript as well as other languages. It's universal.

RegEx is broadly used for datavalidation but can be used for searching for substrings as well.

There is a lot of guides on the internet on this topic.

I found one for you. take a look :)

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/re.shtml

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your question, You want to search relating string to your database or etc. You can do it this so many ways. But "jQuery String Functions" are very helpful your solution and also look at [Regular Expression](http://regexone.com/). Please try it code below for inspiration related to "string functions".

```
var myRecords:Array  = ["xjavascriptfasf","cavascript","abascript"];
var searchValue = "javascript";

for(var i =0; i<myRecords.length; i++) {
    console.log(myRecords[i].search(searchValue));
}
```

output should be like this :

```
1
-1
-1
```

Thats means in your database and user search matched and returned it correct string.

Also please take a look at this "jquery string functions" http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/jquery-string-functions.html

I hope this is help your trouble.

Comment: Cool ! nice to hear that.